# Android Sql. Query single coloumn, multiple values

Tags: android, sqlite

I have database with three columns.
I would like to query the database, based on one column which can have multiple values.

For single parameter we can the normal query method where cardName is String[]

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(Database.TABLE_COUPON_CARD, allColumns,Database.COLUMN_CARD_NAME + " = ?", cardName, null, null,null);
```

but if there are more than one value, I get a `Android SQLite cannot bind argument exception`

For multiple values of the same column we can use `IN statement` but, here how do I write the `QUERY` or how should i form the `rawQuery`

```
String whereClause = Database.COLUMN_CARD_NAME+ " IN(?)";
         Cursor cursor = database.query(Database.TABLE_COUPON_CARD, allColumns,whereClause,new String[][]{cardName}, null, null,null);
```

Android QUERY doesnot take array of array.
What should the correct query be?

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION**
Currently I have created a method which dynamically creates the clause.

```
 private static StringBuilder buildInClause(String[] myStringArray){
    StringBuilder fullString=new StringBuilder();
    fullString.append("(");
    for(int i=0;i<myStringArray.length;i++){
        fullString.append(" '"+myStringArray[i]+"' ");
        if(i!=myStringArray.length-1){
            fullString.append(",");
        }

    }
    fullString.append(")");
    return fullString;

}
```

If anyone has any other solution please do share.

Answer (score 1):

For two values: `IN(?,?)`. For three values: `IN(?,?,?)`. Get the idea? Each `?` corresponds to a single literal in the selection args array.

Comment: In clause will need to be generated dynamically, based on no of values being sent. in(?) when passing one value, in(?,?) when passing two values